# Ionic Bluetooth plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to connect my app to a BLE device (not another smartphone).
I'm searching for a bluetooth ionic plugin and I saw that there are three of them but I don't understand the differences very well.
There are some resources / tutorials about ionic bluetooth plugins that can help understand these?

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-le

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial -> is to be used only to connect to an Arduino device right?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [ble](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble): Only allows Connecting to a peripheral. You will find examples on their [Github page](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central)
- [bluetooth-le](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-le): Also enables your device to become a peripheral itself. The description states it

> covers most of the API methods available on Android and iOS

They also offer help and examples on [Github](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle)

- [bluetooth-serial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial): This is not a plugin for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) but for Bluetooth Classic.

---

You need to select the most fitting plugin for your application

Comment: I need to connect to a device (no smartphone) with ble module. It's a remote controller to drive some cars.
And after connection I need to send commands to the device that the device will redirect automatically to the devices that are attached to the remote controller.

Comment: It sounds like the first library is enough for your scenario. I don't think the first one is able to handle BLE security (pairing and bonding), if you need it you might want to choose the second one

Comment: No need to pairing. Only connect, retriever data or send data

Comment: Great, that's the easy part :)